# Sending data from node MCU using Arduino IDE with the help of variables

Tags: mysql, arduino, arduino-esp8266

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

#define dht_dpin 0

const int analog_ip = A0;

int inputVal  = 0;

DHT dht(dht_dpin, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {

  dht.begin();

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Humidity sensor \n\n");

  delay(1000);

}
void loop() {

  float h = dht.readHumidity();

  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  Serial.print("current humidity = ");

  Serial.print(h);

  Serial.println("%  ");

  Serial.print("\ncurrent temperature = ");

  Serial.print(t);

  Serial.println("C  ");

  inputVal = analogRead (analog_ip);

  Serial.print("\ncurrent heartbeat = ");

  Serial.println (60000/inputVal);

  delay(1000);

}
```

This is my working code. I want to send data from these sensors to the database. How can I do this using variables of my code? I am using Node MCU as I/O processor.

Answer (score 0):

visit this githup page

[Github MySQL Connector with Samples](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino)

and download the lib.
There are many samples how to use MySQL / MariaDB.